# Vagrant not installing pip during provision

Tags: python, bash, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

Here is my `bootstrap.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
apt-get install python-pip

if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

I ran

```
vagrant reload --provision
vagrant ssh
```

but when I type `pip` it returns

> The program 'pip' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
>       sudo apt-get install python-pip

I verified I was able to

```
sudo apt-get install library
```

in the ssh terminal, so I am not sure what is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i guess it's installed, but for some reason is not added to path, so you can't invoke it by typing pip, check if it's really installed

Comment: Try adding the `-y` flag to the command where you install `pip`, just like you have it for `apache2`, and provisioning again. This tells `apt-get` to assume "yes" for all questions, including "are you sure you want to install these packages". This flag is important for non-interactive APT use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing `apt-get install python-pip` with `apt-get -y install python-pip` as Chris already said in the comments.